# Informatica administrator is not available

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have done the installation of  informatica power 9.6.1 for the first time during installation by the step 7. I got an error:

> informatica administrator is not available

The domain was created successfully but the informatica administrator is not accessible. I have click continue once installation done I am not able to login admin page it shows like:

> http status 404 -/administrator/.

Can anyone help on this issue to get it resolved?

Comment: Check if the service is running - you'll probably need to run it.

Comment: As Maciejg mentioned, please check if informatica service is up and running? Also check if the user thats running the service/process has proper privileges to run it, to read-execute all infa binaries etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the correct URL (especially the correct port) for Informatica Administrator page in the

1. $INFA_HOME/tomcat/conf/server.xml
2. $INFA_HOME/tomcat/temp/_AdminConsole/conf/server.xml

Usually the URL is like `https://[put the IP of the server where you installed Informatica]:[take the port you find in the XML files above]/administrator/`